# Lazy initialization of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a class with `std::unique_ptr` members which are initially initialized to `nullptr` and later assigned an actual object. They also use custom deleters.

I have two questions regarding this scenario: Should I use `std::unique_ptr::reset()` or copy assignment operator to assign a value to a unique pointer which was first initialized to `nullptr`? And if the latter is the case, then how can I make the code below work?

```
class MyClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, void(*)(Foo*)> m_foo;
    std::unique_ptr<Bar, void(*)(Bar*)> m_bar;
}

MyClass::MyClass() : m_foo(nullptr, ReleaseFoo), m_bar(nullptr, ReleaseBar) { }

bool MyClass::init()
{
    m_foo.reset(CreateFoo()); // works ok
    m_bar = std::unique_ptr<Bar, ReleaseBar>(CreateBar()); // 'ReleaseBar' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Dx'
}
```

Also, would the answer change if no custom deleters were involved (i.e. use reset with custom deleters and copy assignment otherwise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reset`or the *move* assignment operator to assign a new value.

The problem with your statement

```
m_bar = std::unique_ptr<Bar, ReleaseBar>(CreateBar()); // 'ReleaseBar' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Dx'
```

is, as the error message you quote indicates, that `ReleaseBar` is not a valid template argument. Earlier code uses `ReleaseBar` in a way consistent with this being a function name. In the earlier code the corresponding template argument was `void(*)(Bar*)`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Should I prefer one over the other or are they basically the same?

Comment: More or less the same. reset would delete the existing ptr and resets with the new one.